# How does this bitwise manipulation change a single bit a particular index?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I understand what each of the individual operators does by itself, but I don't know how they interact in order to get the correct results.

```
def kill(n, k):
    #Takes int n and replaces the bit k from right with 0. Returns the new number
    return n & ~(1<<k-1)
```

I tested the program with the `n` as 37 and `k` as 3.

```
def b(n,s=""):
    print (str(format(n, 'b')) +" "+ s)

def kill(n, k):
    b(n, "n ")
    b(1<<k-1, "1<<k-1")
    b(~(1<<k-1), "~(1<<k-1) ")
    b( n & ~(1<<k-1)," n & ~(1<<k-1) ")
    return n & ~(1<<k-1)



#TESTS

kill(37, 3)
```

I decided to run through it step by step.
I printed both the binary representations of both `n` and `~(1<<k-1)` but after that I was lost. `~(1<<k-1)` gave me `-101` and I'm not sure how to visualize that in binary. Can someone go through it step by step with visualizations for the binary?

Comment: Have you heard about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)?

Comment: @wim I have. I know what all of the operators in this problem do, I'm just having trouble visualizing how they interact to get the result.

Comment: *"Can someone go through it step by step with visualizations for the binary?"* - Why don't *you*?

Comment: @HeapOverflow I tried but I got confused once I got -101. I'm not sure how the negative is represented in binary. I'm not sure if the 101 is the two's complement or if the two's complement is different than that.

Comment: @NeutralTax  Maybe you need to understand better 2's complement - does this answer your question: [Bitwise AND (&) between negative and positive numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46044936/674039)

Answer (score 0):

All numbers below are printed in binary representation.

Say, `n` has `m` digits in binary representation. Observe that `n & 11...1` (m ones) would return `n`. Indeed, working bitwise, if `x` is a one-bit digit (0 or 1), then `x & 1 = x`.
Moreover, observe that `x & 0 = x`. Therefore, to set up `k`th digit of number `n` to 0, we need to do operation `and` (`&`) with `11111..1011..1`, where 0 is exactly on `k`th location from the end.

Now we need to generate `11111..1011..0`. It has all ones except one digit. If we negate it, we get `00000..0100..1` which we get by `1 << k-1`.

All in all: `1 << k-1` gives us `00000..0100..0`. Its negation provides `11111..1011..1`. Finally, we do `&` with the input.

Comment: How does `1 << k-1` generate the number we need

Comment: `1 << k -1` shifts 1 by k-1 positions to the right. For example, `1 << 2 = 100`. Note that we usually assume that all binary numbers have a fixed number of digits (e.g., 8). Therefore, strictly speaking, `1` (which equals `000 000 01`) becomes `000 001 00`

Comment: `1 << 2` returns `4=100`. Oh, I see the confusion, thanks @mkrieger1.